# PIG : Columns into rows

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I have a file contains this :

```
id_v^id_f^id_s1,id_s2,id_s3,id_s4
id_v1^id_f1^id_s2,id_s3,id_s4
id_v2^id_f2^id_s2,id_s1,id_s4
```

this file is a "^" delimited csv. 
i want to normalise it this way using pig :

```
id_v^id_f^id_s1
id_v^id_f^id_s2
id_v^id_f^id_s3
id_v^id_f^id_s4
id_v1^id_f2^id_s2
id_v1^id_f2^id_s3
id_v1^id_f2^id_s4
...
```

Can anyone help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Let assume this is my file.Lets say the file name is id_v.txt

```
id_v^id_f^id_s1,id_s2,id_s3,id_s4
id_v1^id_f1^id_s2,id_s3,id_s4
id_v2^id_f2^id_s2,id_s1,id_s4
```

Below is the Pig code

```
A = load '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/id_v.txt' using PigStorage('^') as(v:chararray,f:chararray,data:chararray);
B = foreach A generate v,f,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(data)) as data;
dump B;
```

Below is the O/P Produced by above code..

```
(id_v,id_f,id_s1)
(id_v,id_f,id_s2)
(id_v,id_f,id_s3)
(id_v,id_f,id_s4)
(id_v1,id_f1,id_s2)
(id_v1,id_f1,id_s3)
(id_v1,id_f1,id_s4)
(id_v2,id_f2,id_s2)
(id_v2,id_f2,id_s1)
(id_v2,id_f2,id_s4)
```